# using lexical this in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was learning about lexical `this` in ES6, and I countered this example :

```
let person = {
    name : 'Alex',
  cars : ['Ferrari','Jaguar','Bugatti','Cadillac'],
  toString : function(){
    for(let car of cars){
            console.log(`${this.name} has ${car}`)
        }
  }
}

person.toString();
```

so let's say I want to convert the toString function to an array function so I'll have this :

```
let person = {
    name : 'Alex',
  cars : ['Ferrari','Jaguar','Bugatti','Cadillac'],
  toString : () => {
    for(let car of cars){
            console.log(`${this.name} has ${car}`)
        }
  }
}

person.toString();
```

in this example `cars` is undefined, why I'm getting that, and how can I call `cars` from the `person` object in that example.

the same goes for this :

```
let person = {
    name : 'Alex',
  cars : ['Ferrari','Jaguar','Bugatti','Cadillac'],
  toString : () => {
    cars.forEach(car => console.log(`${this.name} has ${car}`));
  }
}

person.toString();
```

Comment: step 1, don't use an arrow function, it's `this` is different. step 2, iterate `this.cars`, not `cars`

Comment: but, for your last example, don't use arrow for toString, but DO use arrow for forEach function ... so (shorthand) `toString() { this.cars.forEach(car => ...`

Comment: `cars` is an object property.  It must be accessed with `obj.cars` syntax.  You cannot access it as `cars`.  It's not a local variable.  In Javascript, there is no implicit attachment of `this` to a property like there is in some other languages.  You will have to reference `person.cars`.

Answer (score 3):

The first example is already broken.

> in this example `cars` is undefined, why I'm getting that

There is no variable with name `cars`. Whether or not you are using an arrow function doesn't make a difference.

> how can I call `cars` from the `person` object in that example.

Use a method or function expression and reference it with `this.cars`:

```
let person = {
  name : 'Alex',
  cars : ['Ferrari','Jaguar','Bugatti','Cadillac'],
  toString() {
    for(let car of this.cars){
            console.log(`${this.name} has ${car}`)
        }
  }
}
```

Arrow functions cannot be used as *instance methods*, because in instance methods you don't want lexical `this`. Learn more: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Answer (score 0):

Because of your arrow function that your `this` apply to your object which the function you called.

**correct**

```
let person = {
  name : 'Alex',
  cars : ['Ferrari','Jaguar','Bugatti','Cadillac'],
  toString : function() {
   this.cars.forEach(car=>{
        console.log(`${this.name} has ${car}`)
    })
  }
}

person.toString();
```

The last arrow function in `foreach` is apply this of your object that why you didn't need to use clourse like `this.cars.forEach(...)(this.name)`.

Comment: *"you didn't need to use clourse like this.cars.forEach(...)(this.name)"* makes no sense to me.